# Confusion with Factory pattern regarding Liskov's Substitution Principle, code maintainability and Unit Testing?

Tags: c#, design, design-patterns, language-agnostic, liskov-substitution

I have a confusion regarding Factory Pattern there are basically two ways You can implement that.

Approach 1:

```
public interface IProductFactory
{
    IProduct GetProductA();
    IProduct GetProductB();
    IProduct GetProductC();
}

public class ProductFactory : IProductFactory
{
    public IProduct GetProductA()
    {
        //some implementation goes here
    }
    public IProduct GetProductB()
    {
        //some implementation goes here
    }
    public IProduct GetProductC()
    {
        //some implementation goes here
    }
}
```

Approach 2:

```
public enum ProductType
{
    ProductA = 1,
    ProductB = 2,
    ProductC = 3
}

public interface IProductFactory
{
    IProduct GetProduct(ProductType productType);
}

public class ProductFactory : IProductFactory
{
    public IProduct GetProduct(ProductType productType)
    {
        switch (productType)
        {
            case ProductType.ProductA:
                //return IProduct with specific implementation
                break;
            case ProductType.ProductB:
                //return IProduct with specific implementation
                break;
            case ProductType.ProductC:
                //return IProduct with specific implementation
                break;
            default:
            //return null
        }
    }
}
```

**Pros of both approaches**

Approach 1:

1. benefit of compile time checks that the implementation class will be
   forced to provide the corresponding methods.

Approach 2:

1. Implementation will have a benefit of shorter no. of lines of code.
2. Interface does not become fragile, it won't change as the new
   products keep on adding.

**Cons of both approaches**

Approach 1:

1. Lines of code becomes large.
2. As more number of Products are implemented, the interface changes
   and hence it is hard to follow Liskov's Substitution Principle.

Approach 2:

1. Since it is hiding internal details of GetProduct, it is hard to
   tell what the Factory will return when a specific type of enum is
   passed.
2. You might get into run time exceptions

**I am still struggling to decide on which approach to use?**

---

**Note:** I am only aware of these two approaches, there might be different approaches also.

Comment: Why do you need an interface for the product - IProduct? Will products have different behaviour? This is a candidate for the abstract base class.

Comment: @CodeWorks Products will be having different implementations/ behaviours as You can say it. Yes in reality it is an abstract class but for sake of simplicity I have shown it as an Interface here.

Answer (score 4):

Both approaches break Liskov Substitution Principle. Correct implementation will look smth. like:

```
public interface IProductFactory
{
    IProduct GetProduct();
}

public class Product1Factory : IProductFactory
{
    public IProduct GetProduct()
    {
        return new Product1(); //configure instance here
    }
}

public class Product2Factory : IProductFactory
{
    public IProduct GetProduct()
    {
        return new Product2(); //configure instance here
    }
}

public class Product3Factory : IProductFactory
{
    public IProduct GetProduct() //configure instance here
    {
        return new Product3();
    }
}
```

Comment: I have never seen Factory Implementation like that. If I do it like that what is the point of even creating a factory? Please explain.

Comment: Apologies if that sounded rude :)

Comment: Here probably you will need another factory to create those factories. Indeed I also do not see the use here...

Comment: @shankbond If you look at [Abstract Factory class diagram](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_factory_pattern#Class_diagram), it is exactly what I wrote here. E.g. ADO.NET implements this pattern with its [DbProviderFactory](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.common.dbproviderfactory.aspx)

Comment: @oalan You don't need factories to create another factories:). There will be a place in the code where you know which factory you want to use, be it in code or a connection string in configuration file. I didn't say that this pattern should be used frequently. It's quite heavyweight for what devs usually need. In most real-world cases IoC framework is the factory that does all the magic.

Answer (score 2):

Approach 2 is the classical [Factory Pattern](http://www.oodesign.com/factory-pattern.html). This pattern is nothing to do with LSP. To ensure LSP is not violated in the client programs, you need to carefully design `IProduct` interface in such a way that the client program that is operating on `IProduct` would continue to operate without any modification irrespective of the concrete product that actually implements `IProduct`. If, you observe you are violating LSP redesign the interfaces.

For example it may be better to create one interface for a category of products if these categories differ in the way client communicates with them.

```
public interface IPerfume
{
    //Methods specific perfume products
}

public interface IAutomobile
{
    //Methods specific to automobiles
}
```

Then, you define one factory for each category of products. `PerfumeFactory` to create perfume products and `AutomobileFactory` to create automobiles.

The example may not sound fancy but that is all I can think of now.

Comment: +1. this is closest to the right answer of the 3 so far. The points about `IProduct` are right on. In addition, Approach 1 is basically trying to be the [Abstract Factory Pattern](http://www.oodesign.com/abstract-factory-pattern.html) without being an abstract factory. Both approaches suffer from interface-itis, IMHO. They are simply not necessary here.